# Could not create file: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, shell, double-quotes

I want to create create a `qcow2` image for a virtual disk size of `7G` so I'm doing `virsh_pool=/home/test/abc` and then

```
qemu-img create “${virsh_pool}/foo.qcow2” 7G
```

But it gives me an error like

```
Formatting '“”/home/test/abc”/foo.qcow2”', fmt=raw size=7516192768
qemu-img: “”/home/test/abc”/foo.qcow2”: Could not create file: No such file or directory
```

When I do

```
qemu-img create /home/test/abc/foo.qcow 7G
```

It gets created but not the above way that I wan to do.
What am I missing or doing wrong in this way?.

Comment: `/home/test/abc` is different than `/home/test/pool`

Comment: `“` are not `"` quotes.

Comment: @jordanm check now

Comment: @KamilCuk check now

Comment: @RajatSingh, what they are saying is that when it says `'“”/home/test/abc”/foo.qcow2”'`, there are too many quotes around it, and they are not valid quotes to Linux. Linux doesn't understand curly quotes; it treats them as characters, and there's no directory that starts with curly quotes, so it correctly says "I can't do it, I give up"

Comment: Instead: `qemu-img create "${virsh_pool}/abc.qcow2" 7G`

Comment: qemu-img: /home/test/abc/foo.qcow2: Could not create file: No such file or directory

Comment: "*No such [...] directory*"

Comment: @RajatSingh Please rewrite your script and filenames in such a way that you're comfortable sharing the unmodified output (without redacted filenames), and then run `bash -x yourscript` and edit your post to include the exact copy-pasted output. This is important because such edits can unintentionally change seemingly insignificant details (like a stray space, brace or quote)

Comment: Try `mkdir -p "${virsh_pool}"` first.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (copy and paste it):

```
d="${virsh_pool}"
if [[ -d "$d" ]]
then
    qemu-img create "$d/foo.qcow2" 7G
else
    printf 'ERROR\n' >&2
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

Try without quotes:

> qemu-img create ${virsh_pool}/foo.qcow2 7G

Comment: ` Formatting '/home/test/abc/abc.qcow2', fmt=raw size=7516192768
qemu-img: /home/test/abc/foo.qcow2: Could not create file: No such file or directory `

Comment: Please *do* use quotes, but use the *right* ones. Variable references should (almost) always have plain ASCII double-quotes around them. That is, use `"${virsh_pool}/foo.qcow2"`, not `“${virsh_pool}/foo.qcow2”` (fancy Unicode quotes), `${virsh_pool}/foo.qcow2` (no quotes), or even `'${virsh_pool}/foo.qcow2'` (single-quotes).